# Custom Ajax request in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I inserted this script in header.php:

```
var loadData=function(){
   jQuery.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"json_gallery_data.php"
   }).done(function(data){
      var videos=JSON.parse(data);
      for(var i in videos){
         alert("ok");
      }
   })
}
```

Then is appearing that the file:json_gallery_data.php isn't found
What may I do?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making a big assumption here that *json_gallery_data.php* exists in your theme (not at the root of your WordPress install). As a result, you need to pass the correct URI to your AJAX function:

```
url: "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/json_gallery_data.php'; ?>"
```

Read more about `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri).

Comment: Thanks a lot rnevius

Comment: You're welcome. Please select this answer as "correct", if it solves the problem (click the check mark to the left).